# The fields "strategy", "strategyOptions" in a keyspace object are undefined when client encoding is set to map: Map

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-node-driver

[Cassandra DB version is 4.0.5](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/releases/tag/cassandra-4.0.5), [cassandra nodejs driver version is 4.6.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver?activeTab=readme).

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76209205/9413035) I'm creating a cassandra nodejs client with the following code:

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',
    encoding: {
        map: Map
    }
})
```

When I try to get keyspaces with `client.metadata.keyspaces` the result is the following:

```
...
"system_auth": {
        "name": "system_auth",
        "strategyOptions": {},
        "strategy": undefined,
        ...
    },
```

The fields "strategy", "strategyOptions" are not populated by cassandra nodejs driver.
If I don't specify encoding for client:

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1'
})
```

then the result of `client.metadata.keyspaces` is:

```
...,
"system_auth": {
        "name": "system_auth",
        "strategy": "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy",
        "strategyOptions": {
            "replication_factor": "1"
        },
        ...
}
```

The keyspace strategy here is populated.
Why is this happening and how can I get the keyspaces metadata in the situation when I need to specify the encoding for the client?